# Excel Hlookup function returning the first character in table

Tags: excel, vba, formula, lookup, vlookup

I am using Hlookup to find in a row where the value is "A", and then subsequently take a binary value in the same column and use this as the selected cells value.

I am only using the formula bar for this part. The cells formula is:

```
"=HLOOKUP("A",A13:Z19,1)"
```

Row 13: SNPHUATVBKWJZYMQGXFCROEILD    (Each character is assigned to an individual cell).

In row 19, each cell is taken up by 5 binary digits, so to keep things tidy I will write the decimal numbers:

```
10  3   2   20  18  6   24  2   12  21  30  4   6   26  19  22  9   13  5   24  0   31  12  15  24  9
```

The issue is that, while my formula should return 6, as that is the corresponding value within the same column as the letter "A", it returns 9, which is the first cell on the top right of the search criteria table.

Also worth noting is that if I post in a different cell a similar formula but perhaps change the search criteria to a different character such as "H", then the same error will occur, returning a 9.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: use the fourth criterian of the HLOOKUP `FALSE`: `=HLOOKUP("A",A13:Z19,7,FALSE)`

Comment: Hlookup is Vlookup turned sideways. If you want to learn more about why you need to specify the 4th parameter, read [Vlookup – why do I need TRUE or FALSE?](http://www.teylyn.com/vlookup-why-do-i-need-true-or-false/)

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful help, as well as the formatting of my post.  I have had a look at the article and changed a cell to the adaption demonstrated within Scott's comment, though I am now receiving the error "#N/A".  This must mean that it cannot find the exact match, though it is most certainly within the inputted array.  Confusingly, Excel giving the wrong return value, as it did initially, indicates that the formula was resulting in the appropriate array being searched.

Comment: Check your data, you may have spaces and or other non visible characters that are keeping it from finding a match.  Without the forth criterion it will return an approximate match, as in it will try to find where the match fits in the array and it assumes that the array is sorted ascending.

Comment: Thank you for your continued support.  It seems to me as if, despite of changing the formula parameters, when I copy the formula to another cell, the same result is also carried over.  I have checked the formula auto update settings and I cannot see a problem there.  I'm not sure if this thread should be discontinued, since the issue may be vastly different to how I had initially described it.